# Dertermine if the inputs have 3 consecutive integers

Tags: python

How to determine if in the 5 inputs(integer) there are 3 consecutive numbers example:

if my input is: 1 2 3 4 5

it will print out `True` or if my inputs are `1,2,3,9,8` or `5,6,7,2,1` or `8,9,1,2,3`
will print out `True`

this is my current code:

```
print 'Entering Values into a list:'

a = int(raw_input (""))
b = int(raw_input (""))
c = int(raw_input (""))
d = int(raw_input (""))
e = int(raw_input (""))

a = int(a)
b = int(b)
c = int(c)
d = int(d)
e = int(e)
list_a = [a,b,c,d,e]

if list_a[0] < list_a[1] and \
    list_a[1] < list_a[2] and \
    list_a[2] < list_a[3] and \
    list_a[3] < list_a[4]:
    print True
else:
    print False
```

is there an easier way that i can cover all the possible combinations?

Comment: Your code doesn't check for 3 consecutive numbers. It checks if the list is strictly increasing, which is not really relevant.

Comment: _" 5 inputs(integer) there are 3 consecutive numbers"_ This is not quite clear. Are you trying to determine if, given a sequence of 5 integers, 3 of them are ordered strictly ascending. Or isn't that not much more understandable than your initial statement?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You only need to test first three letter you enter, since you are looking for consecutive numbers. Try this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-

print 'Entering Values into a list:'

a = int(raw_input (""))

b = int(raw_input (""))

c = int(raw_input (""))

d = int(raw_input (""))

e = int(raw_input (""))


if (b - a == 1 and c - b ==1) or\
(c - b == 1 and d - c == 1) or\
(d - c == 1 and e - d == 1):
    print True
    exit()
print False
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this: (this will work if list contains more than 3 numbers)

```
from itertools import combinations

list_a.sort()
trio = False
for nums in combinations(list_a,3):
    if nums[0] + nums[2] == 2 * nums[1] and nums[2]-nums[0] == 2:
        trio = True
        break
print trio
```